# Dropwizard 0.8 upgrade, filter error

Tags: java, filter, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I am upgrading from from v0.7.1 to v0.8 and have found that the Jersey filter functionality that we are using has been deprecated. The following line:

```
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getContainerRequestFilters().add(new FilterAuthentication());
```

(pretty much identical to the [DW manual](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#jersey-filters) )

now gives a compiler error:

> `"The method`getContainerRequestFilters()`is undefined for the Type`ResourceConfig`"`

Please can someone point me in the right direction on how to upgrade this feature.
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropwizard [0.8.x](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-core/0.8.0-rc1) uses Jersey 2.x. Most of the methods in `ResourceConfig` changed. For Jersey 2, you can use the general purpose [`register`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#register%28java.lang.Class%29) method, used to bind any JAX-RS component.

Dropwizard also has a `register` method chained to `jersey()`, so there we don't *have* to call `getResourceConfig()`, as `jersey().register()` will forward to the config's `register` method.

So either of these will work

```
env.jersey().register(...);

env.jersey().getResourceConfig().register(...);
```

Also see the Jersey 2 [ResourceConfig API](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#register%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: peeskillet, awesome - many thanks. Using the general purpose "register" is more consistent and makes more sense.